# How to repeat the first row 3 times than do the same thing fot the next rows in R

Tags: r

I am learning to use R language, if anyone can help me, I will be very grateful
This is an example of what I want to do:
Original data:
1
2
3
4
5

New data I want:
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5

I tried to use `rep()`, but it repeats the whole data 3 times

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `each`. `?rep` says *Each element of ‘x’ is repeated ‘each’ times.*

Comment: a<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
repeated_data <- rep(a, each = 3);
 repeated_data